# xml file with no columns recognized by XML source

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, ssis

I have an XML file with the following content (some sensitive data replaced with 'DummyData')

```
  <Alert>
    <AlertID>23210B</AlertID>
    <Title>DummyData</Title>
    <PublishDate>3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM</PublishDate>
    <Severity>03</Severity>
    <ResponseNecessary>Yes</ResponseNecessary>
    <ThreatDate>6/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ThreatDate>
    <DueDate>
   </DueDate>
   <SystemStandard>Yes</SystemStandard>
    <Type>DummyData</Type>
     <Overview>DummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyData</Overview>
   <NIRTAnalysis>&lt;p&gt;N/A&lt;/p&gt;</NIRTAnalysis>
   <ThreatAsessment>&lt;p&gt;N/A&lt;/p&gt;</ThreatAsessment>
   <ProductsAffected>&lt;p&gt;DummyData 10 SP4 LTSS&lt;/p&gt;</ProductsAffected>
   <RequiredActions>DummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyData</RequiredActions>
   <AdditionalInformation>DummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyData</AdditionalInformation>
   <ExternalReference>DummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyData</ExternalReference>
   <PatchID>
   </PatchID>
 </Alert>
```

And the following xsd file generated by SSIS:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Alert">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AlertID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Title" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PublishDate" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Severity" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResponseNecessary" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ThreatDate" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DueDate" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SystemStandard" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Overview" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NIRTAnalysis" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ThreatAsessment" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProductsAffected" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RequiredActions" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AdditionalInformation" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ExternalReference" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PatchID" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My problem is when I use XML Source to load the file but the source doesn't recognize the columns. I'm guessing it thinks the file has nested nodes because the only way I can get it to see any columns is with the following XSD below, which will see all the columns but all as separate output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="Alert">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AlertID" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Title" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PublishDate" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Severity" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ResponseNecessary" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ThreatDate" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DueDate" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SystemStandard" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Type" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Overview" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NIRTAnalysis" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ThreatAsessment" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProductsAffected" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RequiredActions" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AdditionalInformation" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ExternalReference" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PatchID" type="xs:string" />
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
```

I don't know a lot about XLST, but I know I can flatten the file that way, but to me, it is flat.  Are there any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?  I believe I just have an xsd problem, but what you see was generated by SSIS.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it doesn't recognize the columns'? Do you see the element Alert as an output but not its children?

Comment: I don't see anything when I go to look at the columns.  It is all blank.  But when I use the 2nd xsd, I can see all the children of Alert, but as seperate outputs or as if I'm using a conditinoal split in a Data Flow Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the XML itself.
Please add a root element to the xml file and try again with a new SSIS-generated xsd after adding the root.

xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
<Alert>
....
</Alert>
</Root>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand, when you typed "XML should look like:", there is no more code...what are you referring to?